# Transformar [hh:mm] em float (ex: 01:30 ==> 1.5) no python

Tags: python

possuo uma lista de dados no formato [hh:mm] e quero converte-lo em float.

ex:

**horas**
01:00
01:35
00:45
00:20

gostaria de tranformar esses varoles em 1.0, 1.5833, 0.75, 0.3333 pra conseguir **3.67** como resposta, e ao fim mostrar **03:40** como resposta final.

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer somar esses valores, então na verdade eles não são "horas", e sim "durações". São conceitos diferentes:

- um **horário** representa um momento específico do dia. Ex: a reunião será às duas horas da tarde.
- uma **duração** representa uma quantidade de tempo. Ex: a reunião durou duas horas (eu não disse que horas ela começou ou terminou, apenas quanto tempo ela durou)

O que pode confundir é que ambos usam as mesmas palavras (horas, minutos, segundos) e até mesmo podem ser escritos do mesmo jeito ("10:00" pode ser tanto 10 da manhã quanto um cronômetro mostrando que já se passaram 10 horas).

Sendo assim, o que você tem aí são representações de diferentes durações, pois não faz sentido "somar horários": 2 da tarde + 3 da manhã é igual a que? Não faz sentido - mas somar uma duração de 2 horas com outra de 3 horas faz sentido (uma reunião durou 2 horas e outra durou 3, o total é 5 horas de duração).

---

Dito isso, em Python durações são representadas por [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects). Então bastaria criar o `timedelta` a partir dessas strings, somá-los e obter o resultado final:

```
from datetime import timedelta

duracoes = ['01:00', '01:35', '00:45', '00:20']
total = timedelta()

for d in duracoes:
    horas, minutos = map(int, d.split(':'))
    total += timedelta(hours = horas, minutes = minutos)

total_minutes = int(total.total_seconds()) // 60
print(f'{total_minutes // 60:02}:{total_minutes % 60:02}')
```

E para formatar, usei o formato `02` para que o número seja impresso com o zero à esquerda caso necessário (se você fizer apenas `print(total)`, o resultado será `3:40:00`).

---

Repare que você **não** precisa transformar "01:35" em `1.5833`, para depois somar tudo e transformar de volta em "03:40", dá para somar os `timedelta`'s diretamente.

Mas claro que se quiser, também dá:

```
duracoes = ['01:00', '01:35', '00:45', '00:20']
total = 0
for d in duracoes:
    h, m = map(int, d.split(':'))
    total += h + (m / 60)

horas = int(total)
minutos = int(60 * (total - horas))
print(f'{horas:02}:{minutos:02}')
```

Dependendo do caso, talvez dê diferença com a solução anterior por causa de algum arredondamento, mas a ideia básica é essa (de qualquer forma, eu ainda prefiro usar `timedelta`, que já cuida dos detalhes de como somar tempos, sem que você precise se preocupar com isso).

---

Outra forma de fazer é criar uma função que transforma a string em `timedelta`, e usar [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) juntamente com [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
from datetime import timedelta

def to_timedelta(duracao):
    horas, minutos = map(int, duracao.split(':'))
    return timedelta(hours = horas, minutes = minutos)

duracoes = ['01:00', '01:35', '00:45', '00:20']
# transforma todas as strings em timedelta e soma
total = sum(map(to_timedelta, duracoes), timedelta())

total_minutes = int(total.total_seconds()) // 60
print(f'{total_minutes // 60:02}:{total_minutes % 60:02}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que a hora esteja em uma string,  você poderia primeiro separar as horas dos minutos:

```
entrada = '01:35'
hora, minuto = entrada.split(':')
```

Em seguida converter os minutos para o intervalo de 0 a 1 e em seguida somar nas horas:

```
resultado = int(hora) + (int(minuto) / 60)
print(resultado) # 1.5833...
```